# Laravel Returned a Blank Page with "IF" validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am trying to solve this problem. I want to make validation, the user must select at least 3 values before he can proceed. I tried to use `count($array)` but it's not working, I know I am doing something wrong, but I don't what. When I tried the code before it returned a blank page

In my `onboarding.blade.php`, I have this form

```
    <form action="{{ url('/onboarding') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
      @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="radio-item">
       <!-- <input class="form control" name="category_id" value="{{$category->id}}" type="hidden"> -->
       <input type="checkbox" id="category_id" name="category_id[]" value="{{$category->id}}">
          <label for="name">{{ $category -> title }}</label>
        </div>
        @endforeach

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit">Proceed to Authors</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

In my `OnboardsController.php` I have this

```
public function categoryUser (Request $request)
{
    $category_id = request('category_id');

    if (count($category_id) >= 3) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));
        return redirect ( route ('onboarding_author')); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what should you do if there are < 3? You have not written code for what to do so it does nothing.

Comment: I don't understand please

Comment: Your code says what to do IF >=3 but it does not say what to do IF it is <3..... there is no ELSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a side note, you could actually use the validator if you would like. You could use rules like so:

```php
'category_id' => 'array|min:3',
'category_id.*' => 'integer',
```

You can use the Request object to do quick validation:

```
public function categoryUser(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'category_id' => 'array|min:3',
        'category_id.*' => 'integer',
    ]);

    // ... passed validation
}
```

If this fails validation it will end up causing a redirect back.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Validation - Available Rules - array](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-array)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Validation - Available Rules - min](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-min)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Validation - Quick Start - Writing the Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)

Answer (score 0):

What if your condition is false! you don't write. So move your return statement outside the if condition

```
public function categoryUser (Request $request)
{
    $category_id = request('category_id');

    if (count($category_id) >= 3) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));
    }
    return redirect ( route ('onboarding_author'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox)'s solution is correct but if you don't wanna redirect your user directly you can manually redirect him with following method:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   // Validation Fails Here...
   return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```